# Salesforce1 Error: "Invalid Key v.active" What does it mean?

Tags: visualforce, salesforce1-app, salesforce1-platform

I'm getting the error message below in Salesforce1, but I can't find any reference to it on google or in Salesforce's documentation. What can it mean?

The error happens when the user clicks on a detail page button which is implemented with a (mobile-enabled) Visualforce page. That VF page has a custom controller which sends an email and then returns the user to the Case that they pressed the button from.

It works fine on a desktop/browser, and it works fine for me on Samsung S4. My customer says it works on his tablet, but not on his S4 (which is where this screenshot is from).

Ideas?

Code for the VF page:

```
<apex:page standardController="Case" extensions="CaseSendFirstResponseExtension" action="{!doSend}" title="Case Send First Response">
<apex:sectionHeader title="Sending First Response..." />
<apex:pageMessages />

<apex:form >
  <apex:commandButton value="Back" action="/{!Case.id}"/>
</apex:form>

</apex:page>
```

[image: Error Message]

Comment: In the controller what is "v"? should it be v.IsActive?

Comment: Thanks for the response, but there is no variable "v" in the page or controller. My suspicion is that Salesforce1 is showing some sort of internet error message, but not giving much to go on...

Comment: Same issue here. I had our Inside Sales Rep change the product being sold from one product to another. Now, I get this error on my Note 3.

Comment: fyi: I believe v is a auro/lightening variable, but I doubt this is something you can fix yourself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is actually quiet common on Android. I've reported it myself to Salesforce and would encourage you to do so as well. Here is another [thread](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/63283/invalid-component-tried-calling-function-set-with-arguments-v-inactive-false/64172#64172) where I answered a similar question with some links to this being a [known issue](http://media.good.com/documents/gsf1_1.0.1GA_relnotes_android.pdf).